# What does Keep in akka stream mean?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am learning akka stream and encounter Keep.left and Keep.right in the code:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("KafkaProducer")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val source = Source(List("a", "b", "c"))
val sink = Sink.fold[String, String]("")(_ + _)

val runnable: RunnableGraph[Future[String]] = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.right)
val result: Future[String] = runnable.run()
```

What does here Keep.right mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every stream processing stage can produce a materialized value which can be captured using `viaMat` or `toMat` (as opposed to `via()` or `to()`, respectively).  In your code snippet, the using of `source.toMat(sink)` indicates that you're interested in capturing the materialized value of the source and sink and `Keep.right` keeps the right side (i.e. sink) of the materialized value.  `Keep.left` would keep the materialized value on the left side (i.e. source), and `Keep.both` would allow you to keep both.

More details is available in relevant sections in the [Akka Streams documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html).

Answer (score 1):

`Keep.left` keeps only the left (first) of the input values. `Keep.right` only keeps the right (second) of two input values.

Comment: What is the input value of the above example.

Comment: First input is the source. Second input is the sink.

Answer (score 0):

Because jvm does type erasure, Akka does not care about the type between Source Flow Sink when designing Stream, but Source Flow Sink is a typed class.
In order for the type to pass between the components, you need to attach a description value, which is the meaning of Keep.
By default, the message type in the final result is consistent with the leftmost Source , Keep.left(). You can also set it to something else like Keep.right().

Strictly speaking, Keep specifies the value type, not the value.
[enter link description here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html)

```
val r3: RunnableGraph[Future[Int]] = source.via(flow).toMat(sink)(Keep.right)
```

Change "Keep.right" to "Keep left":

```
val r3: RunnableGraph[Future[Int]] = source.via(flow).toMat(sink)(Keep.left)
```

Will get "type mismatch "  error.