# How does Akka Stream's Keep right/left/both result in a different output?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to wrap my head around how Keep works in Akka streams. Reading answers in [What does Keep in akka stream mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116358/what-does-keep-in-akka-stream-mean), I understand that it helps to control we get the result from the left/right/both sides of the materializer. However, I still can't build an example were I can change the value of left/right and get different results.

For example,

```
implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("Playground")
implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

val sentenceSource = Source(List(
  "Materialized values are confusing me",
  "I love streams",
  "Left foo right bar"
))

val wordCounter = Flow[String].fold[Int](0)((currentWords, newSentence) => currentWords + newSentence.split(" ").length)
val result = sentenceSource.viaMat(wordCounter)(Keep.left).toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.right).run()

val res = Await.result(result, 2 second)
println(res)
```

In this example if I change values from keep left to keep right, I still get the same result. Can someone provide me with a basic example where changing keep to left/right/both values results in a different outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, since:

```
sentenceSource: akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[String,akka.NotUsed] = ???
wordCounter: akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[String,Int,akka.NotUsed] = ???
```

both have `NotUsed` as their materialization (indicating that they don't have a useful materialization),

```
sentenceSource.viaMat(wordCounter)(Keep.right)
sentenceSource.viaMat(wordCounter)(Keep.left)
```

have the same materialization.  However, since `Sink.head[T]` materializes to `Future[T]`, changing the combiner clearly has an impact

```
val intSource = sentenceSource.viaMat(wordCounter)(Keep.right)

val notUsed = intSource.toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.left)
// akka.stream.scaladsl.RunnableGraph[akka.NotUsed]

val intFut = intSource.toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.right)
// akka.stream.scaladsl.RunnableGraph[scala.concurrent.Future[Int]]

notUsed.run    // akka.NotUsed

intFut.run     // Future(Success(12))
```

Most of the sources in `Source` materialize to `NotUsed` and nearly all of the common `Flow` operators do as well, so `toMat(someSink)(Keep.right)` (or the equivalent `.runWith(someSink)`) is far more prevalent than using `Keep.left` or `Keep.both`.  The most common usecases for source/flow materialization are to provide some sort of control plane, such as:

```
import akka.Done
import akka.stream.{ CompletionStrategy, OverflowStrategy }

import system.dispatcher

val completionMatcher: PartialFunction[Any, CompletionStrategy] = { case Done => CompletionStrategy.draining }
val failureMatcher: PartialFunction[Any, Throwable] = { case 666 => new Exception("""\m/""") }

val sentenceSource = Source.actorRef[String](completionMatcher = completionMatcher, failureMatcher = failureMatcher, bufferSize = 100, overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.dropNew)

// same wordCounter as before
val stream = sentenceSource.viaMat(wordCounter)(Keep.left).toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.both)    // akka.stream.scaladsl.RunnableGraph[(akka.actor.ActorRef, scala.concurrent.Future[Int])]

val (sourceRef, intFut) = stream.run()

sourceRef ! "Materialized values are confusing me"
sourceRef ! "I love streams"
sourceRef ! "Left foo right bar"
sourceRef ! Done

intFut.foreach { result =>
  println(result)
  system.terminate()
}
```

In this case, we use `Keep.left` to pass through `sentenceSource`'s materialized value and then `Keep.both` to get both that materialized value and that of `Sink.head`.

Comment: Thanks Levi, your example was very helpful : )  Small clarification needed. From my understanding, the ActorRef has a materialized value which I can pass along the stream. What are other kind of values which I can materialize and pass along the stream? Does it always have to be an ActorRef? (I am trying to think how can I have something that is not: NotUsed)

Comment: Another example is in the Alpakka Kafka connector, there's the ability to have a consumer control: this allows you to stop the stream in a controlled manner (e.g. you can stop consumption but not complete the stream until offsets have been committed).  Another example is `Source.tick`, which produces elements periodically until the materialized value is canceled.