# When materialiser is actually used in Akka Streams Flows and when do we need to Keep values

Tags: scala, graph, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to learn Akka Streams and I'm stuck with this materialization here.

Every tutorial shows some basics `source via to run` examples where no real between `Keep.left` and `Keep.right` is explained. So I wrote this little piece of code, asked IntelliJ to add a type annotation to the values and started to dig the sources.

```
val single: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
val flow: Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] = Flow[Int].map(_ * 2)
val sink: Sink[Int, Future[Int]] = Sink.fold[Int, Int](0)(_ + _)


val run1: RunnableGraph[Future[Int]] =
  single.viaMat(flow)(Keep.right).toMat(sink)(Keep.right)

val run2: RunnableGraph[NotUsed] =
  single.viaMat(flow)(Keep.right).toMat(sink)(Keep.left)

val run3: RunnableGraph[(NotUsed, Future[Int])] =
  single.viaMat(flow)(Keep.right).toMat(sink)(Keep.both)

val run4: RunnableGraph[NotUsed] =
  single.viaMat(flow)(Keep.right).toMat(sink)(Keep.none)
```

So far I can understand that at the end of the execution we can need the value of the `Sink` that is of type `Future[Int]`. But I cannot think of any case when I gonna need to keep some of the values.

In the third example it is possible to acces both left and right values of the materialized output.

```
run3.run()._2 onComplete {
  case Success(value) ⇒ println(value)
  case Failure(exception) ⇒ println(exception.getMessage)
}
```

It actually works absolutely the same way if I change it to `viaMat(flowMultiply)(Keep.left)` or `none` or `both`.

But in what scenarios the materialized value could be used within the graph? Why would we need it if the value is flowing within anyway? Why do we need one of the values if we aren't gonna keep it?

Could you pelase provide an example where changing from left to right will not just break the compiler, but will actually bring a difference to the program logic?

Comment: I used akka stream several times and never needed to use that "other" value returned.

IMO, given that no other streaming library needs this, it seems like unneeded complexity. It may provide a solution in some case, but equaly may indicate a more complex than needed solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Akka Stream's Keep right/left/both result in a different output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682901/how-does-akka-streams-keep-right-left-both-result-in-a-different-output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most streams, you only care about the value at the end of the stream.  Accordingly, most of the `Source` and nearly all of the standard `Flow` operators have a materialized value of `NotUsed`, and the syntactic sugar `.runWith` boils down to `.toMat(sink)(Keep.right).run`.

Where one might care about the materialized value of a `Source` or `Flow` stage is when you want to be able to control a stage outside of the stream.  An example of this is `Source.actorRef`, which allows you to send messages to an actor which get forwarded to the stream: you need the `Source`'s materialized `ActorRef` in order to actually send a message to it.  Likewise, you probably still want the materialized value of the `Sink` (whether to know that the stream processing happened (`Future[Done]`) or for an actual value at the end of the stream).  In such a stream you'd probably have something like:

```
val stream: RunnableGraph[(ActorRef, Future[Done])] = 
  Source.actorRef(...)
    .viaMat(calculateStuffFlow)(Keep.left)  // propagates the ActorRef
    .toMat(Sink.foreach { ... })(Keep.both)

val (sendToStream, done) = stream.run()
```

Another reasonably common use-case for this is in the Alpakka Kafka integration, where it's possible for the consumer to have a controller as a materialized value: this controller allows you to stop consuming from a topic and not unsubscribe until any pending offset commits have happened.