# akka stream materialized value using different options

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am new to akka stream and want to understand how materialization in streams works

```scala
//Print sum of elements from 1 to 10
val newSource = Source(1 to 10)
val flow      = Flow[Int].fold(0)((a, b) => a + b)
val sink      = Sink.foreach(println)
val sumFuture = newSource.via(flow).toMat(sink)(Keep.left).run()
```

It prints the value `55` using `Keep.left` and `Keep.right`. How does the two differ?

I want to explore to see `Keep.left` and `Keep.right` give different values as well how we can use `Keep.both`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Akka Stream's Keep right/left/both result in a different output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682901/how-does-akka-streams-keep-right-left-both-result-in-a-different-output)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Materialised value can be produced by both sink and source. One creates a runnable graph by combining a source to a sink. `Keep` defines which materialised value to keep when combining

- `Keep.right` picks materialised value of the sink
- `Keep.left` picks materialised value of the source
- `Keep.both` picks both in the form of a tuple
- `Keep.none` ignores both and picks `NotUsed`, ie a marker to indicate that there is no materialised value.

By default, `Keep.left` is used in operations `via`, `to` etc.

Following examples highlight this

Given a `Source[Int, String]` and a `Sink[Int, Future[Int]]`

```scala
val source: Source[Int, String] = Source(List(1, 2, 3)).mapMaterializedValue(_ => "Source Mat Value")
val sink: Sink[Int, Future[Int]] = Sink.fold(0)(_ + _)
```

We can combine a `source` and `sink` to create a runnable graph with different materialised values.

```scala
val left: String = source.to(sink).run() //same as toMat(...)(Keep.left)
val right: Future[Int] = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.right).run()
val both: (String, Future[Int]) = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()
```

Now, if we run it and print every materialised value it produces following

```
left=Source Mat Value
right=Future(Success(6))
both=(Source Mat Value,Future(Success(6)))
```

Please don't mix up materialised value with processing of elements of the stream.

Consider following `fold` stages

```scala
val flowFold: Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] = Flow[Int].fold(0)(_ + _)
val sinkFold: Sink[Int, Future[Int]] = Sink.fold(0)(_ + _)
```

`flowFold` applies `fold` function to every element in the stream and pushes **one single** value representing the result of `fold` to downstream. This element can be further processed if needed.

Whereas, `sinkFold` is the final stage in a graph and it cannot push elements further downstream. It uses materialised value `Future[Int]` to return the `fold` result when graph has processed all elements and completed.

> if the value of `Flow.fold` is 55 should this be the materialised value of the flow instead of `NotUsed`.

No, value `55` is not a materialised value. It's pushed as an element to downstream sink.

You can "catch" element `55` in a materialised value with the help of `Sink.head`

```scala
val flow: Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] = Flow[Int].fold(0)(_ + _)
val alternativeFoldSink: Sink[Int, Future[Int]] = flow.toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.right)
```

> Every stage can produce materialised value then (why) can't `Flow.fold`
> generate materialised value.

Yes, every stage may produce a materialised value. But `Flow.fold` is designed not to do so. Most of the `Flow` definitions do not provide materialised values. If you want to use materialised value and `fold`, I'd suggest to use `Sink.fold`

Comment: I tried `val newSource = Source(1 to 10)
  val flow      = Flow[Int].fold(0)((a, b) => a + b)
  val sumFuture1 = newSource.viaMat(flow)(Keep.right).toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.both).run()
  sumFuture1._2.onComplete {
    case Success(value) => println(s"The sum is :$value")
    case Failure(ex)    => println(s"The sum cannot be computed :$ex")
  }`
Output is The sum is : Done, it does not print the sum.
I want to emit some integer value from Keep.right and Keep.left both can you show an example `UniqueKillSwitch  ` is a bit complex

Comment: Does source not have materialized value we have used `mapMaterialisedValue

Comment: @coder25 Yes, `Source(List(...))` has materialised value of `NotUsed`. Thus usage of `mapMaterializedValue` to have a materialised value

Comment: why we replaced Flow with Sink.fold does Flow not give materialized value

Comment: Thks for clear explianation if the value of Flow.fold is 55 should this be the materialized value of the flow instead of NotUsed.does that mean we can never have materialised value from Flow

Comment: Please don't mix up materialised value with processing of elements of the stream .Every stage can produce materialised value then can't Flow.fold generate materialized  value

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that a stream stage can have

- a materialized value, which is created when the stream is materialized, before any element has passed through that materialization.  Accordingly, it cannot depend on the values which pass through/into/out of the stream.
- zero or more output values which are passed to the next stage of the stream as the stream runs.

Every stage has a materialized value.  Every stage that isn't a sink potentially has output values.  For sources, in general, the materialized value provides some means to affect the stream's behavior (e.g. the materialized value of `Source.actorRef` is an `ActorRef` which allows you to push elements to the stream by sending a message to that `ActorRef`, or the various Kafka consumer sources in Alpakka Kafka allow you to stop consuming from Kafka without stopping the stream until the stream is drained).

For sinks, in general, the only way to get a value out of the sink is through the materialized value (since there's no output).  Since the materialized value has to be created before any data has flowed through the stream, this is why most sinks materialize to a `Future` (a placeholder for data which isn't yet available) and generally won't complete the value until the stream completes (since `Future`s are write-at-most-once).

Every stage has a materialized value, but not every stage has a meaningful materialized value: for those, the special `NotUsed` value (a singleton) encodes "not meaningful".  Most of the flow stages are in this category: they exist solely to transform input to output.