# Regarding clean shutdown for actor system and akka stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

We wish to accomplish the following on akka stream shutdown

1. The source is stopped,
2. The elements in the stream are completed upto a timeout point
3. then the stream/actor system is shut down

We have the following code for shutting down our actor system (Akka 2.4).

```
    try {
      Await.ready(actorSystem.terminate(), sleepSeconds.seconds)
    } catch {
      case ex: Throwable => log.error("Failed to terminate actor system", ex)
    }
```

I am trying to understand the akka documentation and its not clear to me if we are required to shutdown the materializer (for our akka stream) separately or not? We have a method on the materializer and one on the actor system here.

Or in other words, what is the idiomatic step of operations we should be taking to cleanly/gracefully shutdown our akka stream .

Comment: You might want to have a look to [KillSwitch](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to shutdown the stream before actor system termination. If you don't, you may lose some elements in internal buffers that may not get to the final `Sink`

Consider following example with akka 2.6 (if some APIs are different from 2.4, please adjust yourself)

```scala
implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
val source = Source(LazyList.fill(100_000)(Random.nextInt(100)))
val flow = Flow[Int]
  .throttle(3, 1.second)
  .map { s =>
    println(s);
    s
  }
  .grouped(4)
  .map(s => (s.size, s.max))
val stream = source.via(flow).to(Sink.foreach(println))
val _ = stream.run()
Thread.sleep(5_400)
val _ = Await.result(actorSystem.terminate(), 2.seconds)
println("Terminated")
```

when it runs, you may see final output before actor system termination as following

```
36
84
38
32
(4,84)
29
Terminated
```

it produces element `29` that is stuck in `grouped` and never reaches final `Sink.foreach(println)`.

This is possible to overcome with the help of a [kill switch](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#controlling-stream-completion-with-killswitch)

```scala
implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
val killSwitch = KillSwitches.single[Int]
val source = Source(LazyList.fill(100_000)(Random.nextInt(100))).viaMat(killSwitch)(Keep.right)
val flow = Flow[Int]
  .throttle(3, 1.second)
  .map { s =>
    println(s);
    s
  }
  .grouped(4)
  .map(s => (s.size, s.max))
val stream = source.viaMat(flow)(Keep.left).toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.both)
val (kill, done) = stream.run()
Thread.sleep(5_400)
kill.shutdown()
val _ = Await.result(done, 2.seconds)
println("Terminated")
val _ = Await.result(actorSystem.terminate(), 2.seconds)
```

Now the last output will be correct

```
10
64
77
6
(4,77)
74
24
(2,74)
Terminated
```

and output `(2,74)` proves that `grouped` was flushed.

Please note usage of `viaMat` and `toMat` to capture two materialized values. (You can read about materialized values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65405064/4803842))

- `killSwitch` returned by `KillSwitches.single[Int]`
- `Future[Done]` returned by `Sink.foreach`

`KillSwitch` can only initiate a termination of a stream but you still have to wait for the stream completion. This can be done via `Future[Done]` from the `Sink`

```scala
kill.shutdown()
val _ = Await.result(done, 2.seconds)
```

This initiates a shutdown and then waits for it to complete.

##### Where kill switch should be integrated

Answering question in the comments, the kill switch needs to be integrated as close to the source as possible. The kill switch has to integrated before all of the side effects, in my example these are `map` and `sink` because of `println`. In real world, side effect can be storing a value in a database or sending a message to external queue/topic.

Kill switch emits a source completion signal and this signal must pass downstream to initiation termination logic for each flow and sink.

Comment: Thanks. I had one question. If I have a source.via(flow1)....via(sink) (as in multiple flows in between the source and the sink), the killswitch will appear just before the sink correct?

Comment: The closer it is to the source the better. There’s a completion signal initiated by the killswitch and it has to pass via a flow to initiate a termination/flush. If it’s close to the sink, then you’ll face a similar problem as in the first example