# Usage of Keep.right / Keep.left within Akka Streams does not affect the result

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm trying to come up with different examples in order to understand the work of Keep.left or Keep.right

I have the following code:

```
val numSource = Source(1 to 10)
  val numSource = Source(1 to 10)
  val incrementFlow = Flow[Int].map(x => x +1)
  val doubleFlow = Flow[Int].map(x => x * 10)

  val someFuture: NotUsed =           numSource.via(incrementFlow).via(doubleFlow).to(Sink.foreach(println)).run
  val someOtherFuture: Future[Done] = numSource.viaMat(incrementFlow)(Keep.left).viaMat(doubleFlow)(Keep.right).toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.right).run()
  val someOtherFuture2: Future[Done] = numSource.viaMat(incrementFlow)(Keep.right).viaMat(doubleFlow)(Keep.right).toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.right).run()
```

I was assuming that in **someOtherFuture** `viaMat(incrementFlow)(Keep.left)` will ignore the increment of the element since I'm using materialized value of the source (and not the resulted one = Keep.right) and the result of the graph will be equal to num * 10.
BUT all 3 lines are giving me back the same result:
//20,30,40 .. 110

What I'm missing here? I have already checked the documentation and was trying to implement simple examples, but it looks that I got wrong the idea of materializing.
Or maybe it happens since I'm working with a sequenced graph w/o any merged flows that receive two inputs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Akka Stream's Keep right/left/both result in a different output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682901/how-does-akka-streams-keep-right-left-both-result-in-a-different-output)

Comment: @LeviRamsey I saw this post, that's why I assumed that toMat(Sink..)(Keep.right) will keep the value. Can you please assist me with understanding of how I can skip on results of incrementFlow and just to use its input for the doubleFlow?

Comment: The materialized value doesn't in general affect the values flowing through the stream, so since you have the same values from `numSource` with each materialization and the functions in the `map`s are deterministic, you'll always get the same values.

Comment: In your examples, the materialized value is just the result that gets handed back when you actually start running the stream (the `NotUsed` (to signal that there's nothing useful) and the `Future[Done]` (which will complete when the stream finishes or report what error caused the stream to fail) in your example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The materialized value is best understood as a means for code outside of a stream which has started (whether still running or completed/failed) to interact with the stream in some way: it's the return value of running the stream, and we can see the effect of `Keep.right`/`Keep.left` in the code you posted:

```scala
val someFuture: NotUsed =           numSource.via(incrementFlow).via(doubleFlow).to(Sink.foreach(println)).run
val someOtherFuture: Future[Done] = numSource.viaMat(incrementFlow)(Keep.left).viaMat(doubleFlow)(Keep.right).toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.right).run()
val someOtherFuture2: Future[Done] = numSource.viaMat(incrementFlow)(Keep.right).viaMat(doubleFlow)(Keep.right).toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.right).run()
```

The materialized value of `numSource`, `incrementFlow`, and `doubleFlow` is `NotUsed` which basically means that those stages don't expose any way for code outside of the stream to interact with the stream.

For `Sink.foreach`, the materialized value is a `Future[Done]` which will complete successfully with `Done` if the stream runs until the source has exhausted and all other stages succeeded, or complete with a failure containing the cause of the stream failing.

Comment: many thanks for this excellent explanation. Is there a way to convert source or one of the flows from my example to the valuable type instead of `NotUsed`? In AKKA documentation, source is usually defined as `NotUsed`

Comment: Most of the predefined `Source`s/`Flow`s have a `NotUsed` materialized value because there's not really anything that would make sense.  There is `mapMaterializedValue`, which lets you convert the materialized value, though there's not really anything you could sanely convert `NotUsed` to.